# what are the sharepoint permissions required to update the shared view of a web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

what are the sharepoint permissions required to update the shared view of a web part?
I'm on SharePoint 2010

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's anyone with permissions to "Add and Customize Pages". Out of the box that would be site collection administrators and people/groups with the Full Control or Design permission set.

Comment: this one worked better for me: SPBasePermissions.ManagePersonalViews

Answer (score 1):

Full Control or Design permission.

More info here [User permissions and permission levels (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx)